# MergeSort IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

So I'm learning about MergeSort right now to solve a problem on Project Euler.

I am trying to sort a list 5163 names alphabetically. I did some research and found that MergeSort would be a fairly efficient way of doing so.

So I coded up an implementation based off of this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/merge_sort_algorithm.htm).

Below are my `mergeSort` and `merge` methods.

```
public static List<String> mergeSort(List<String> list){

    if (list.size() == 1){ //if fully divided
        return list;
    }

    List<String> leftSide = list.subList(0, list.size()/2);
    List<String> rightSide = list.subList(list.size()/2 + 1, list.size());

    leftSide = mergeSort(leftSide);
    rightSide = mergeSort(rightSide);

    return merge(leftSide, rightSide);

}

public static List<String> merge(List<String> listA, List<String> listB){

    List<String> listC = new LinkedList<String>();

    while (!listA.isEmpty() & !listB.isEmpty()){ //while both have elements
        if (listA.get(0).compareTo(listB.get(0)) > 1){ //if stringA is greater than stringB 
            listC.add(listA.get(0));
            listA.remove(0);
        } else { //if stringB is greater than stringA
            listC.add(listB.get(0));
            listB.remove(0);
        }
    }

    while (!listA.isEmpty()){ //while listA has elements 
        listC.add(listA.get(0));
        listA.remove(0);
    }

    while (!listB.isEmpty()){ //while listB has elements
        listC.add(listB.get(0));
        listB.remove(0);
    }

    return listC;

}
```

The problem is that when I try and use the `mergeSort` method with my list of names, it gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(1) > toIndex(0)

Which is pointing at this line:

```
List<String> rightSide = list.subList(list.size()/2 + 1, list.size());
```

I don't really understand why it is happening. It seems to me that I have used the exact same method as shown in the tutorial.

Also, from what I understand, this error is telling me that the size of my list is zero. This would be the only way in which `list.size()/2 + 1` could equal one and `list.size()` could equal zero. However, I don't see why my list could be zero. Because it is going to be divided until the size is one, and then it will be returned.

The only way I could see it equalling zero was if it was zero to begin with, but I have confirmed that my `list.size()` is 5163 to start with.

Could someone help me point out what I am doing wrong? I am sure it is something really simple, but since I have just started learning this, I am not sure what it is.

**EDIT:**

I check the list's size here:

```
System.out.println(namesArray.size()); //prints "5163"
namesArray = mergeSort(namesArray);
```

So how could my list ever have a size of zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only way I could see it equalling zero was if it was zero to begin with, but I have confirmed that my list.size() is 5163 to start with.

There is a second way. Consider what happens deep into your recursion when on entry to `mergeSort` the input sublist contains two elements.

```
List<String> leftSide = list.subList(0, list.size()/2);
```

The above becomes `list.sublist(0,1)`. Since the ending index is *exclusive*, the sublist contains one element. Then:

```
List<String> rightSide = list.subList(list.size()/2 + 1, list.size());
```

This becomes `list.sublist(2,2)`. Again, since the ending index is *exclusive*, this creates a ***list of length zero, or an emtpy list***.  Now when you reach the recursive calls

```
leftSide = mergeSort(leftSide);
rightSide = mergeSort(rightSide);
```

the left side recursion works but the right side recursion passes a zero-length list.  At the top of `mergeSort` you have

```
if (list.size() == 1){ //if fully divided
    return list;
}
```

which checks for the terminating condition of list size 1, but does not stop the code from attempting to process an empty zero-length list.  This is what causes your exception immediately after this point.

If you changed the test to `if (list.size() <= 1)` you'd have prevented the exception, but would still have a problem since some of the elements would not have been sorted due to the ending index problem.

The correct solution is to change one line:

```
List<String> rightSide = list.subList(list.size()/2 + 1, list.size());
                                                    ^^^
        Remove this----------------------------------^
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I found just now by debugging it. If I am correct, removing the +1 should fix this yes?

Comment: Yes.  I'd also check for zero length and throw a runtime exception. You cannot guarantee the caller of this method will always do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an empty list, you call

```
List<String> rightSide = list.subList(0/2 + 1, 0);
```

So your from index is bigger than the toIndex. And that raises the exception.

Form the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)):

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.
>    This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view instead of a whole list. For example, the following idiom removes a range of elements from a list: 
>             list.subList(from, to).clear();
>
> Similar idioms may be constructed for indexOf and lastIndexOf, and all of the algorithms in the Collections class can be applied to a subList.
>       The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)
>
> Parameters:fromIndex - low endpoint (inclusive) of the subList
>
> toIndex - high endpoint (exclusive) of the subListReturns:a view of the specified range within this list
>
> Throws:IndexOutOfBoundsException - for an illegal endpoint index value (fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size || fromIndex > toIndex)

You have to check if the list is empty.

Comment: Similar to what I just commented on @Saurav's answer, I understand that this is telling me that my list.size() is zero, but I don't understand how this is possible given that my list is not zero to start with.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry Use a Debugger and you find it out

Comment: It is not zero to start with. One of the sublists (deep into recursion) has zero length due to the index error.